# windows forms: textbox with history

Tags: winforms, textbox, history, edit

does anyone know about a windows forms control that acts like the address bar of a browser?

it is just like a textbox, but to the right there is a dropdown menu that shows the history of previously entered text.

thanks a lot!

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11238602/c-sharp-textbox-show-previous-written-texts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at properties "AutoCompleteCustomSource", "AutoCompleteMode" and "AutoCompletesource" on TextBox class.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a ComboBox for this. Just add the previous entries to the item list. If what you actually want is AutoComplete, the WinForms TextBox control supports that natively.

Comment: What is the Edit control?

Comment: I think I meant TextBox nine years ago ;)