# C# textbox show previous written texts

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

For example if you go to facebook and press double click on the login textbox, then there are some Logins that previous someone wrote. Is there any way to make this dropdown of previous inputs on C# textbox? I don't want combobox.

Comment: I think those come from history of your Browser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the [TextBox.AutoCompleteMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletemode)  and [TextBox.AutoCompleteSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletesource) properties of the TextBox. You need to do something on the following lines:

```
namespace WindowsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        AutoCompleteStringCollection autoComplete = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            autoComplete.Add(textBox1.Text);

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
            textBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
            //auto.Add(textBox1.Text);
            textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = autoComplete;
        }
    }
}
```

Check the following Tutorial: [AutoComplete TextBox In WinForms Windows Forms Application](http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2009/01/winforms-autocomplete-textbox-using-c.html)

Comment: Nice is almost complete.. The problem is that is finding the previous text if you start with correct letter... For example if you wrote "Program", you should write "p" to find it

Comment: @Loclip, you may save the entries from the textbox to a db or any persistent storage and then retrieve it and set the textbox AutoCompleteCustomeSource like `txtName.AutoCompleteCustomSource = namesCollection;`. After that pressing p will bring program if it is in the source. Check the 2nd part of the article I have posted