# How can i make combobox editable in .Net?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

My form has a combobox which reads user input. But i want to allow the user to enter his own choice apart from the ones in dropdown list. I have set the following properties

1. AutoCompleteSource to collection
2. AutoCompleteMode to SuggestAppend
3. AutoCompleteSource to CustomSource

When i run the application i am getting exception object reference not set to an instance of object.

Comment: The exception has nothing to do with the combobox being editable or not.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11238602/c-sharp-textbox-show-previous-written-texts

Comment: @Stevewhere can i find original ques?